# How to sort particular DOM nodes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

I have an html code as shown below in which I want sort html elements present after last h2 tag.

```
<div class="organization-results">
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">B</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">A</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle START -->
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">C</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Pqr Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Tuv Vbu</h3>
   </div>
    <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle END -->
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
<div class="organization-results">
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">B</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">A</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle START -->
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">C</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>      
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Pqr Abc</h3>      
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Tuv Vbu</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
    <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
    <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle END -->
</div>
```

This what I have tried but I think more need to be done.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('.organization-results .organization-subtitle:last-child .organization-title');

var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
        itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
}

itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
          ? 0
          : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can assume that we will always sort the `.organization-code` after the last h2 (not the third) tag and those elements will be the last in their container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a quite strict structure you can come up with a selector which will select all the `.organization-code` elements after the last `.organization-subtitle`:

```
.organization-subtitle:last-of-type ~ .organization-code
```

From there, it's a simple matter of extracting these elements in DocumentFragment and reappend them sorted after that `.organization-subtitle:last-of-type` element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector( '.organization-results' );
const limit_selector = ".organization-subtitle:last-of-type"
const items = [ ...container.querySelectorAll( limit_selector + " ~ .organization-code") ]
  .sort( (a, b) =>
    a.textContent.localeCompare( b.textContent )
  );
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
frag.append( ...items );

container.querySelector( limit_selector ).after( frag );
```

```html
<div class="organization-results">
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">B</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">A</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle START -->
   <h2 class="organization-subtitle">C</h2>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Pqr Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Xyz Abc</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Abc Xyz</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="organization-code">
      <h3 class="organization-title">Tuv Vbu</h3>
   </div>
    <!-- Sort contents after last organization subtitle END -->
</div>
```